# Laravel, unique columns

Tags: laravel, validation, unique, rules

I need validate if field already exist, throws error, but with this code no errors are triggered

Laravel 7

```
table: departamento
column: id int incremental
column: departamento varchar(150)
column: idPais       int
```

store method

```
$this->validate($request, ['departamento' => Rule::unique('departamento','idPais')->where('departamento',$request->depto)->where('idPais',$request->pais)]);
```

Try with this too

```
 $rules = [
'depto' => [Rule::unique('departamento')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('departamento','=', $request->depto)->where('idPais','=', $request->pais);
}),]
];
 $this->validate($request,$rules);
```

with this code, throws this error

```
 $rules = [
'depto' => [Rule::unique('departamento')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('departamento','=', $request->depto)->where('idPais','=', $request->pais);
}),]
];
$this->validate($request,$rules);
```

[image: error]

Thanks!!!

EDIT:

My bad, I need check two fields , departamento and idPais, thanks.

Comment: So basically `departmento` needs to be a unique? How does idPais tie into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of your field name. The unique rule will try to find a record with that column name set to the request value (in your case, `depto`, but your column name is `departamento`). When you are customising the query you are not overriding it, you are adding on top of this default behaviour. From the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique):

> By default, the unique rule will check the uniqueness of the column matching the name of the attribute being validated. However, you may pass a different column name as the second argument to the unique method:

With that in mind, you could either change the unique rule to set the column to `departamento` and not `depto` as per below, or change the request to send `departamento` attribute instead of `depto`:

```php
$rules = [
'depto' => [Rule::unique('departamento', 'departamento')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('idPais','=', $request->pais);
}),]
];
```